# Display name For File provider extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions, fileprovider-extension, files-app

I would like to know how to modify the display name programatically on a file provider extension as shown in the image below

[image]

How to add this "Personal"

Comment: How are you listing the names? Need more info

Comment: I've never used the File Provider classes but perhaps it is from the `displayName` of `NSFileProviderDomain`.

Comment: I am not. The image is just the initial page of native files app. I am developing files provider extension for my app where i would like to show the "personal" as others do.

Comment: great! . Will try this @rmaddy